Tomcat and Spring: Issue with Query Param Being Truncated (EVAL Keyword)
I’m encountering an issue with my Spring application running on a standalone Tomcat server (version 8.5.92), where a query parameter value is getting truncated under specific conditions.
Problem:
I’m making the following POST request using Postman and cURL to my Spring Boot application:
curl --location 'http://localhost:8085/studies/S_STD01(TEST)/roles?siteOid=S_EVAL(TEST)'

The issue is that when the query parameter siteOid=S_EVAL(TEST) is sent, my Spring controller only receives the value S_. However, if I change the value of siteOid to something like S_EVAL- (i.e., replacing () with -), the value is correctly passed to the controller as S_EVAL-.
It appears that EVAL() is being treated as some kind of special keyword or expression, which is causing the truncation of the query parameter value.
Tomcat Connector Configuration:
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443"
           maxParameterCount="1000"
           relaxedPathChars="[]|"
           relaxedQueryChars="()[]|{}^&#x5c;&#x60;&quot;&lt;&gt;" />

Environment:

Tomcat Version: 8.5.92
Spring Version: 5.3.27
OS: Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS

Any help or insights into this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Try EVAL(1/0) and look at logs to see where exception is thrown.

Appreciate it, however no exception at all. Just Received S_.

How is your controller declared? Do you have any filters or interceptors setup?

Yes, I have Security and Locale Filters Setup, I have checked there as well by getting the request.getParameterMap() and we see the same issue there as well. But let me check the other filters as well.

Thanks for the help. We do a XSS filter to sanitize the request. The following code is causing this issue. It seems we need to update the pattern to match the entire word EVAL not in part of the words. \b will fix this:
scriptPattern = Pattern.compile("\\eval\\((.*?)\\)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL);

Check you filters. One of them overwrite your params.

Yep, It was issue in the filters.
